# Can you invert a switch in java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Is there a way to invert a switch for example `switch (!(x))`? I'm writing a program and I only want the user to be able to input certain letters. If they input an invalid letter, they would have to input it again. I'm trying to use a switch for this avoiding doing something like

```
switch(x)    
{    
   case a : case b: case c: case d: etc etc    
}
```

because the number of valid inputs are much smaller then the number of invalid ones so I would have like 20 cases.

Comment: can you not use 'default' in your switch here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do

```
switch(x)
{
case 'x' : case 'y': case 'z': //valid; 
break;
default: //invalid;
}
```

Comment: and a break; after default i'd guess

Comment: A break at the last case is redundant

Comment: @Stebra no need - the switch ends anyway after the default block

Answer (score 1):

Can you use more IFs?

Something like:

if(a){}
if(b){}
if(c){}
...
else{}

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can, but there are other ways of doing this.  If I had a `String` that I knew was one character long, and I wanted to take some action if that character were NOT one of a certain set of values (let's say `"a"`, `"b"`, `"h"`, `"y"` or `"n"`), I would write something like this.

```
if ( ! "abhyn".contains(myString)) {
    doStuff();
}
```

This will seem more intuitive to most people than messing round with `switch` and `break` and `default`.

Note that if it's possible for `myString` here to be more than one character, then it's a little messier.